# Telegram bot in C#: How to make it execute code only after receiving a message from the user?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

Please tell me.
how to make the bot report not to start checking immediately, but to wait for a message from the user?

```
        public static async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var message = update.Message;
            // Некоторые действия
            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update));
            if (update.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.Message)
            {
                if (message.Text.ToLower() == "/start")
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "Hi!");
                    return;
                }
                if (message.Text.ToLower() == "check")
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "Enter code ?");
                    message = update.Message;

                    if (message.Text.ToLower() == "kiki2")
                    {
                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "+");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "-");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLZyO.png)

I write check, immediately goes to the else block as an error.
I need the bot to wait for a response from the user, and then go to the if block.

Comment: If the response is a separate message, wouldn't that be an entirely separate invocation of `HandleUpdateAsync`?  I imagine you'd need to store in some way that the bot is expecting a specific message, and then in the next call to `HandleUpdateAsync` handle that message.  *"Waiting"* is very likely the wrong approach, but rather think about it in terms of *"handling the message"*.